# Symfony how could I add fields to my FOSUser?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add a field 'name' to my user and this is how I proceeded

```
 namespace User\UserBundle\Controller;


use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $response = parent::registerAction();


        // ... do custom stuff
        return $response;
    }
```

And this is My userType

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
        ;
    }
```

When I try to add,

```
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

I get this error

```
Method "nom" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig at line
      This is my user class
```

```
namespace User\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true )
     */
    private $nom;
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true )
     */
    private $prenom;



    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set prenom
     *
     * @param string $prenom
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prenom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }
}
```

This is what I have under app/config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6LIr.png)
 What should I do more? Any suggestions please? i'm newly starter with FOSUserBundle. THanks

Comment: what does your User class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it ! I added construct to my userType

```
public function __construct($class)
    {
        parent::__construct($class); 
    }
```

And this is my new services.yml

```
parameters:
    user_user.registration.class: User\UserBundle\Entity\User

services:
    user.form.user:
        class: User\UserBundle\Form\UserType
        arguments: [%user_user.registration.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_userbundle_user }
```

And that's it I hope it helps someOne. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add the nom and prenom fields to the registration form.  So you need to override the FOSUserBundle registration form.  Follow the guide at [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) which shows how to override any form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO

Comment: I have followed the instructions in documentation but i get this error

Answer (score 0):

> This is my config.yml

Do you write it all in config.yml ?

you need to write this code in config.yml:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm 
firewall_name: main
user_class: User\UserBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    form:
        type: user_userbundle_user
```

and the remaining write in ./config/services.yml

```
services:
fos_user.doctrine_registry:
    alias: doctrine
app.form.registration:
    class: UserUserBundle\Form\UserType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: user_userbundle_user }
```

Comment: I don't have services.yml page under my app/config folder

Comment: You need create services.yml in AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
and write this code

Comment: I did that the same problem is still occuring